# How many collections of four points, no three of which are collinear, are there in a finite affine plane?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-designs

Suppose the order of the finite affine plane is $n\geq 2$ (that is, each line has exactly $n$ points). I claim there are

$$\binom{n^{2}}{4} - (n^{2}+n)\left[\binom{n}{4}+\binom{n}{3}(n^{2}-n)\right]\; (1)$$

such collections.

Assuredly, each line yields:

1. $\binom{n}{4}$ collections of $4$ collinear points.
2. $\binom{n}{3}(n^{2}-n)$ collections of $4$ points having $3$ of them collinear. Indeed, each line has $\binom{n}{3}$ collections of $3$ collinear points. But since there are $n^2$ points, for each of these collections we have $n^2-n$ points not on the line to choose from in order to form a collection of $4$ points having $3$ of them collinear.

Hence, each line yields $\binom{n}{4}+\binom{n}{3}(n^{2}-n)$ collections of $4$ points having at least 3 of them collinear. But there are $n^{2}+{n}$ lines and the total number of such collections will then be

$$(n^{2}+n)\left[\binom{n}{4}+\binom{n}{3}(n^{2}-n)\right]\; (2)$$

Finally, since there are $\binom{n^{2}}{4}$ collections of 4 points in total, subtracting $(2)$ from this amount yields $(1)$.

Is this correct? It is in the cases $n=2$ ($1$ collection) and $n=3$ ($54$ collections). Does this type of question fit into a more general setting? That is, well developed counting theories or design theory concepts which answer these types of questions.

Comment: For another approach, how about $\frac{1}{24} (n^2) (n^2 - 1) (n^2 - n) (n^2 - 3n + 3)$?

Comment: In the approach given in the question, it seems to me that for the cases where four points are all colinear, you would be overcounting those cases by a factor of 4 in the exclusion term.

Comment: And adding a correcting term of $3(n^2+n) \cdot \binom{n}{4}$ onto your expression gives something that expands to the same result as what I got with my approach...

Comment: @DanielSchepler I was indeed overcounting, and I know why. Corrected. Thanks for the comment.